# How do I use dependency caching for GitHub actions when listening to development_status events?

Tags: continuous-integration, dependencies, cypress, github-actions

I'm following [this tutorial](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/develop-preview-test) on using preview deployments to run Cypress against, but I don't want to sacrifice dependency caching.

#### Is there a workaround I can reach for?

So far:

I've tried using GitHub's `cache` action, but that has [an error](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/src/save.ts#L19) when attempting to write/read to cache from within a workflow that uses `deployment_status` as the event. [According to GitHub's documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#deployment_status), `GITHUB_REF` is undefined if the event is triggered from a commit, so everything so far makes sense.

Knowing the above, one idea I thought of was manually defining `GITHUB_REF` during the `job`'s `env` scope, but felt like that would not work somehow. This wont work because `hashFiles` isn't a recognized function in this scope:

`GITHUB_REF: ${{ github.ref }}-${{ hashFiles('./yarn.lock') }}`